# Fitting data with a beta distribution using fitdist from fitdistrplus package in R

Tags: r, distributions, goodness-of-fit, fitting, beta-distribution

I have a variable x that corresponds to data from a database. I've been trying to find the best distribution to fit it and looking at the histogram I figured either a normal, weibull or logistic should work.

This is the variable

```r
x <- ShippingLogs$ActualShippingDays
```

Which is taken from [this csv](https://static.us-east-1.prod.workshops.aws/public/6f2f7cb1-bfda-4b34-ae39-928502784393/static/datasets/ShippingLogs.csv) where all values are non negative.

So I used `fitdist` from the `fitdistrplus` library to check out if any of these were good. This is what I did:

```r
fit.norm    <- fitdist(x, "norm")
fit.logis   <- fitdist(x, "logis")
fit.weibull <- fitdist(x, "weibull")
```

Then I plotted it and checked it summary, no problem there so far. However that although the logistic and normal were ok fits they were not excelent. So trying to come up with a better fit I resorted to using `gamlss`. So I did

```r
betterfit <- fitDist(x, k = 2, type = "realplus", trace = FALSE, 
                     try.gamlss = TRUE)
summary(betterfit)
```

Which told me that the best fit would be a beta distribution, specifically a GB2. However when I try to do

```r
fit.beta <- fitdist(x, "beta")
summary(fit.beta)
plot(fit.beta)
```

I get `Error in computing default starting values.` which is something that hasn't happened so far. Is there a way I can get the estimated parameters from the `gamlss` `fitDist` so I can work with the beta distribution?

Comment: Why do you need to fit a distribution model, in particular if the candidates (among the infinite number of distribution families) are completely arbitrary?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see your csv link and recover the exact error message, but I think I can recover a similar or identical error, which I've come across with my own data. Specifically, I have approximately beta-distributed observations, which contain values of 0 and/or 1 (fail to satisfy 0<x<1; beta distribution is defined within the interval [0, 1]).

Here is example data to recover the error, a regular sequence from 0 to 1:

```
> x<-seq(from=0, to=1, by=0.002)
> fitdistrplus::fitdist(x, distr="beta")

<simpleError in optim(par = vstart, fn = fnobj, fix.arg = fix.arg, obs = data,     gr = gradient, ddistnam = ddistname, hessian = TRUE, method = meth,     lower = lower, upper = upper, ...): function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters>
Error in fitdistrplus::fitdist(x, distr = "beta") : 
  the function mle failed to estimate the parameters, 
                with the error code 100
```

You can "fix" this by forcing all boundary x values to be 0<x<1.

```
> x[x==0]<- 0.0001
> x[x==1]<- 0.9999
> fitdistrplus::fitdist(x, distr="beta")

Fitting of the distribution ' beta ' by maximum likelihood 

Parameters:
        estimate Std. Error
shape1 0.9770763 0.05706334
shape2 0.9770761 0.05706333
```

Note that this particular way of dealing with it may not be desirable, depending on the problem at hand. Anyway, I think this is at least partly answers your question.